# my npm wouldn't run correctly when I was trying to initialize it I hope that's not the issue. Can someone just check my work? it's not rendering

Tags: reactjs, json, npm

So my npm and json wouldn't work since the very beginning of the certification. I had two peer reviews on my app one said all functionality was there and another said it's completely unusable. I'm trying to work out all the kinks here but I can't find what's wrong. Please help?

```
import {
    useRef, 
    useState
} from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
    const inputRef = useRef{null};
    const resultRef = useRef{null};
    const [result, setResult] = useState{0};

    const plus = {e} => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setResult((result) => result + Number (inputRef.current.vaule));
    };

    const minus = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setResult((result) => result - Number (inputRef.current.value));
    };

    const times = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setResult((result) => result * Number (inputRef.current.value));
    }

    const divide = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setResult ((result) => result / Number (inputRef.current.value));
    }

    const resetInput = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        inputRef.current.value = 0;
    };

    const resetResult = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setResult((preVal => preVale * 0))
    }

    reutrn (
        <div className="App">
            <div>
                <h1>Simplest Working Calculator</h1>
            </div>
            <form>
                <p ref={resultRef}>result</p>
                <input
                    pattern="[0-9]"
                    ref={inputRef}
                    type="number"
                    placeholder="Type a number"
                    />
                <button onClick={plus}>add</button>
                <button onClick={minus}>subtract</button>
                <button onClick={times}>multiply</button>
                <button onClick={divide}>divide</button>
                <button onClick={resetInput}>reset input</button>
                <button onClick={resetResult}>reset result</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )

};
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below, there were some typos, one major one was `reutrn` instead of `return`.

Another one you might want to check is your hooks initialization:

`const [result, setResult] = useState{0};` <-- wrong

`const [result, setResult] = useState(0);` <-- right

```
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const resultRef = useRef(null);
  const [result, setResult] = useState(0);

  const plus = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setResult((result) => result + Number(inputRef.current.value));
  };

  const minus = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setResult((result) => result - Number(inputRef.current.value));
  };

  const times = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setResult((result) => result * Number(inputRef.current.value));
  };

  const divide = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setResult((result) => result / Number(inputRef.current.value));
  };

  const resetInput = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    inputRef.current.value = 0;
  };

  const resetResult = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setResult((preVal) => preVal * 0);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <h1>Simplest Working Calculator</h1>
      </div>
      <form>
        <p ref={resultRef}>{result}</p>
        <input
          pattern="[0-9]"
          ref={inputRef}
          type="number"
          placeholder="Type a number"
        />
        <button onClick={plus}>add</button>
        <button onClick={minus}>subtract</button>
        <button onClick={times}>multiply</button>
        <button onClick={divide}>divide</button>
        <button onClick={resetInput}>reset input</button>
        <button onClick={resetResult}>reset result</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```